# Keeping Samsung mobile phone cool in car while making a Zoom call

Tags: samsung, temperature

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note20 and sometimes make personal Zoom calls to friends in my car as I live with roommates. I live in the Seattle area, so during the warmer months, it'll get anywhere from 70 to 85 or even 90 degrees Fahrenheit. Today, it's about 70 degrees outside today and I got a notification on my phone that it was overheating, even though I had my car windows open.

I'm thinking I could put my cell phone in an insulated container, and then put that insulated container in a cooler with cold packs in it and use Bluetooth earphones for audio on a Zoom call.

Would that work? Or does anybody else have ideas about how to keep my mobile phone cool in my car while making a Zoom call?

Comment: A little bit cooling may help but I remember that someone tried the something similar and in the end caused damage go the phone because the cooled sensor was a little away from the heat spot of the phone so that the phone overheated but the sensor stayed cool and could not throttle the phone. But if I remember correctly in that case there was direct contact between the ice cold cooler packs and the phone. Without that direct contact it should be safe.

Comment: Wow, it's concerning that a top of the line Samsung phone can't even make Zoom calls without overheating.  70F is well within indoor room temperature, so frankly, that's really bad engineering by Samsung.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket
The outside air temperature was 70F but the car temperature was probably way higher.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you had the windows closed and the AC off.  Even still, if the interior temp was a full 15F above exterior (you would be sweating quite a bit in a stuffy vehicle at that temp, especially if there was significant humidity), 85F is well within the expected operating temperature range for a smartphone... and if it was a video call, the phone would be away from your head allowing it to cool.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my own question. Luckily it's been cold enough in the Seattle area to make Zoom calls in my car and I sometimes turn the video off when my phone gets hot.

When the temperate gets hotter I'll turn the video on my phone off and listen with wireless earphones via Bluetooth.

To further cool off the phone (like if the temp gets up to 85 or 90 degrees Fahrenheit) I'll put small cold packs (using a flexible gel cold pack) in a large insulated water bottle (like Hydro Flask Oasis 128 fl. oz. Container - 1 gal.), put my phone in a thermal phone case (like PHOOZY Apollo Series Thermal Phone Case), and listen to the Zoom call with my camera off via wireless earphones using Bluetooth.

Hopefully this helps someone.